# var been changed to 1 with "if (var = 0 || var == 0)" statement

Tags: c++, c

```
int xx = 0;
if(xx = 0 || xx == 0) printf("4"); // if(TRUE||TRUE) then printf("4")
if(xx == 0) printf("5"); //xx been changed to 1??
printf("6\n");
```

I thought the output will be 456, but the output is 46.
Why?

Comment: @Steve where did you find `x`?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, I was also thinking the same, but that was only tagged c++, is not it? Some will start complaining about it. I'll add it anyways, let's see.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56264674/why-does-this-if-statement-return-true) ?

Comment: This question is most certainly **not** a duplicate of the suggested question. It presents a similar, yet **different** scenario. Some users here are too hasty and reckless on the question-closing trigger, and that's a shame IMO.

Comment: @goodvibration it is not **identical**, but the root cause is the same: the assignment isn't quite as straightforward as it seems.

Comment: @goodvibration seems like an attempt at karma farming from someone who saw that the other question somehow got 20 upvotes. Apparently getting started with SO rep is a problem so people turn to that sort of technique

Comment: @M.M good point: someone else spotted the question which was in the side panel a liitle earlier.

Answer (score 5):

According to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `operator||` has higher precedence than `operator=`, then

```
if(xx = 0 || xx == 0)
```

is same as

```
if(xx = (0 || xx == 0))
```

i.e. `xx` is assigned by `0 || xx == 0`; which is `true`, then implicitly converted to `1` and assigned to `xx` (because `xx` is an `int`), then `xx` is evaluated for the `if` condition and it implicitly converts to `bool` with value `true`; that's why you got the output `"4"`. And since `xx` has been assigned to `1`, you didn't get the output `"5"`.

I think what you want should be

```
if(xx == 0 || xx == 0)
//    ^^
```

Comment: So it's basically `xx = (0 || true)`. Nice!!!